# Calculating Utilization - Figuring Minutes Worked out of Available Minutes

Tags: sql, r, business-intelligence, hana

Trying to calculate a total of minutes that an employee was clocked to labor. The caveat is the way things are clocked here I can't just use a min/max/next/previous because it isn't sequential.

Easier to explain with an example. Here's a simple bit of data that is narrowed down to just one employee for one day. I removed the order/operation but realize every record below is a specific order and operation on that order. The records don't effect each other, so any record could be the latest.

```
STARTDATETIME   STOPDATETIME
8/21/2017 6:57:00 AM    8/21/2017 10:45:00 AM
8/21/2017 6:57:00 AM    8/21/2017 10:45:00 AM
8/21/2017 6:57:00 AM    8/21/2017 10:45:00 AM
8/21/2017 6:57:00 AM    8/21/2017 10:46:00 AM
8/21/2017 6:57:00 AM    8/21/2017 11:28:00 AM
8/21/2017 6:58:00 AM    8/21/2017 11:28:00 AM
8/21/2017 11:58:00 AM   8/21/2017 12:05:00 PM
```

If I manually calculate this I can see the person worked from 6:57 - 11:28 without stop (271 minutes)

And then they also worked from 11:58-12:05 (7 minutes)

So their total for the day was 278 minutes. I'm having trouble figuring out how to calculate this though.

The other data I do have readily available is their clock in and out time for the day, so if it is easier to count the minutes they  *weren't*  clocked to something we can get that as well. (Clock in and out in this example was 5:49 and 12:30 for a total of 401 minutes)

Would love to hear any ideas. I'm going to be displaying charts/graphs using this data in Tableau and for the backend I'm using a HANA database.

Answer (score 2):

For this type of question, I would definitely recommend transforming and prepping the data outside of Tableau in python for example.  Tableau is very good at visualizing data points in Time series, however, your data is irregular and not evenly spaced, and although Table and Level of Detail calculations can traverse across rows, your question is a medium level one, that would be difficult to answer with the tool you're attempting to.

If you can't perform an intermediate transformation, and depending on the number or records and time span of your data, you can brute force a regular time series by performing a Cartesian join (or perhaps blend) with a table of values for every minute and in the date range you're looking at.  Then filter (or create a binary field) out all values for which the open is >= the join data, and close date is < the blend date.  This should provide you with a record and date for every minute that they worked, making it a lot easier to perform calculations on the data.  In your case, you can then just SUM the number records to get the number of minutes worked.

This thread has a lot of good information on wrangling time series data depending on your goal. It also includes more detailed information on how to perform cross joins in Tableau
https://community.tableau.com/thread/151387